# Roslaunch dynamixel serial problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I'm having some problems with the pyserial. I execute chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0, but I get this error:

**self.dxl_io = dynamixel_io.DynamixelIO(self.port_name, self.baud_rate)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_io.py", line 68, in **init**
self.ser.setTimeout(0.015) AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'setTimeout'**

```
... logging to /home/tiburcio/.ros/log/dbbf747c-e5f6-11e5-84ce-e006e6dca0d5/roslaunch-tiburcio-note-3351.log Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://tiburcio-note:44245/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS  * /dynamixel_manager/namespace: dxl_manager  * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/baud_rate: 1000000  * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/max_motor_id: 25  * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/min_motor_id: 1  * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/port_name: /dev/ttyUSB0  * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/update_rate: 20  * /rosdistro: indigo  * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES   /
    dynamixel_manager (dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py)

auto-starting new master process[master]: started with pid [3363] ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to dbbf747c-e5f6-11e5-84ce-e006e6dca0d5 process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3376] started core service [/rosout] process[dynamixel_manager-2]: started with pid [3383] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:92: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.   self.motor_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('motor_states/%s' % self.port_namespace, MotorStateList) /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:93: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.   self.diagnostics_pub = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', DiagnosticArray) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py", line 245, in <module>
    manager = ControllerManager()   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py", line 102, in __init__
    serial_proxy.connect()   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py", line 97, in connect
    self.dxl_io = dynamixel_io.DynamixelIO(self.port_name, self.baud_rate)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_io.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.ser.setTimeout(0.015) AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'setTimeout'
================================================================================REQUIRED process [dynamixel_manager-2] has died! process has died [pid 3383, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py
__name:=dynamixel_manager __log:=/home/tiburcio/.ros/log/dbbf747c-e5f6-11e5-84ce-e006e6dca0d5/dynamixel_manager-2.log]. log file: /home/tiburcio/.ros/log/dbbf747c-e5f6-11e5-84ce-e006e6dca0d5/dynamixel_manager-2*.log Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================ [dynamixel_manager-2] killing on exit [rosout-1] killing on exit [master] killing on exit shutting down processing monitor... ... shutting down processing monitor complete done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228593/roslaunch-dynamixel-serial-problem/) by [bottega](https://answers.ros.org/users/26217/bottega/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please change the baudrate in the launch file to 57142 for most MX-series dynamixels.

---

Originally posted by [solbergen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26485/solbergen/) with karma: 16 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0